# current_timestamp in a PL/pgSQL function always returns the same value

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, current-time

I admit that after working more than 20 years with Oracle databases I find it hard not to think that way. Our new application uses now a PostgreSQL 12.8 instance and I need to write some SQL scripts that will display some progress information as the script is executing.

Say I have this script:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    counter INTEGER;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '% -- started counting', current_timestamp;
    SELECT count(*) FROM my_table INTO counter;
    perform pg_sleep(10);
    RAISE NOTICE '% -- % is the counting result', current_timestamp, counter;
END;
$$
```

When running that I am getting the output below:

```
2022-11-22 02:04:38.339825+00 -- started counting
2022-11-22 02:04:38.339825+00 -- 71690950 is the counting result
```

Initially the `perform pg_sleep(10)` was not in my code but I put it when I seen the same time being displayed in my output both before and after counting the number of records. The counting itself takes a few good seconds so not sure what I am doing wrong or is just my understanding about how I should use this script totally wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is quite clear here:

> PostgreSQL provides a number of functions that return values related to the current date and time. These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time of the current transaction

A PL/pgSQL function always runs in a single transaction, so `current_timestamp` will always return the same value. Think of it as “transaction timestamp”.

To get the wall time, use `clock_timestamp()`.